# Проблема с eval()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот код

```
    users = []
    with open(f'{tdir(__file__)}/data.txt'.replace('\\', '/').replace('b.py/', ''), "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        lines = [x.replace('\n', '') for x in file.readlines()]
        file.close()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        line = eval('{' + line + '}')
        if line != '{}':
            users.append(User(speed = line["speed"], gun = line["gun"], money = line["money"], mode = line["mode"], id = line["id"]))
    return users
```

Проблема с eval(). Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
line = eval('{' + line + '}')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

Что не так?

Comment: Очевидно, в переменной line записан какой-то некорректный код

Comment: Что записано в `line`?

Comment: "speed" : 1, "gun" : 1, "money" : 0, "mode" : start, "id" : мой id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку `start` у вас там без кавычек `"mode" : start`, питон ищет переменную с таким названием, чтобы подставить её значение, и не находит. Возьмите `start` в кавычки `"mode" : "start"`, либо опишите ранее в коде переменную `start = "чего-нибудь"`, если там какое-то другое значение должно быть.